# how to call change event like select on html datalist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create an event that fires on a change, so I can create something like a `<select>` tag, but my code is not working with a `<datalist>`.

This is my HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="team" id="favorite_team" list="team_list">
<datalist id="team_list">
  <option>Detroit Lions</option>
  <option>Detroit Pistons</option>
  <option>Detroit Red Wings</option>
  <option>Detroit Tigers</option>
</datalist>
```

And this is my JQuery code:

```
$('#favorite_team').on('change', function(){    
      alert($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the loop to judge the option which is in the list.

```
$('#favorite_team').on('input', function(){
    var options = $('datalist')[0].options;
    for (var i=0;i<options.length;i++){
       if (options[i].value == $(this).val()) 
         {alert($(this).val());break;}
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mbhz4/10/)

Answer (score 3):

Your selector is wrong, change the id of your input to `favorite` or try this code:

```
$('#favorite_team').on('input', function(){    
      alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: sorry but selector is not the problem here

Comment: In the question the selector of the input was wrong. However, try with the `input` event.

Comment: yeah i have changed but it is working but is also showing alert when i type any word i want it to work only if we select any datalist element

Comment: It seems `input` is the only event you can use.

Comment: i hope thnx for help... :)